# Responding To Buttons While Processing Data Swift IOS

Tags: swift

When running my app on my device, I have a button that brings up a new view controller. In the function viewDidAppear of the new view controller, I begin processing a bunch of data previously entered. This data takes about 15 seconds to be processed. At the top of this new view controller is a navigation bar with a Bar Button Item where the user can touch it to return to the home page. However, during the first 15 seconds while the app is processing the data, the navigation bar and the Bar Button Item is completely unresponsive. Is there any way to be able to interact with the user while processing data at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html

Use `dispatch_async` to launch the 'processing' and `dispatch_main` if/when it needs to update the UI.

Not Swift, but Ray Wenderlich has a couple of tutorials:

- http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial
- http://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful, it's hard to find if you are not sure what your looking for. For anyone else out there, here is a great tutorial: http://tetontech.wordpress.com/2014/06/04/swift-ios-and-grand-central-dispatch/ . The only issue with yours is it is in objective C but it provides lots of depth so it is still very useful!